# CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application in maven

Tags: bash, maven

I'm trying to run a bash script with `maven-antrun-plugin`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <exec
                            dir="${project.basedir}"
                            executable="${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/ant.scripts/npm-install-cleanup.sh"
                            failonerror="true"/>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

here's `npm-install-cleanup.sh`:

```bash
# shellcheck disable=SC2164
# delete generated package-lock
cd node_modules
rm .package-lock.json

cd @tokenysolutions

# @see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/422393
# tldr: deletes everything in ./t-rex save for ./t-rex/build/*
find ./t-rex -mindepth 1 ! -regex '^./t-rex/build\(/.*\)?' -delete

# delete the contracts sub-folder of t-rex/build
cd t-rex/build
rm -rf contracts
```

Running this from `${project.baseDir}` with `sh ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/ant.scripts/npm-install-cleanup.sh` does work and produces the expected result, but when I try running the plugin (by calling `mvn -U clean install` the following error is produced:

```
An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program 
"C:\source\${project.basedir}\src\main\resources\ant.scripts\npm-install-cleanup.sh" (in directory
 "${project.basedir}"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

(of course `${project.basedir}` is a placeholder for an actual directory here).
I have added the `sh.exe` installed by Git to my Path before running this but it didn't appear to help.

I tried using both `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin` and `org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin` both with either calling my `.sh` file directly or as argument to `sh` or `cmd` but nothing seems to work. I either get the shown error message or an empty cmd just hangs. How am I supposed to run my script?

While I am currently trying to run this on Windows 10, my goal is for this to work on Unix as well.

Answer (score 1):

My problem had nothing to do with either plugin in the end (once I figured out their correct usage): I was trying to run a bash script written for Linux on Windows, and my final error had to do with vastly different syntax between Linux's and Windows' FIND commands.